# Any headless browser for node with access to outcoming request body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, headless-browser

I am trying to do some web automation.
There is a website that is transferring a query parameter between its requests, which is constructed with come complicated and obfuscated js code, that browser executes, and this parameter is not stored within cookies or any part of a web page (I think it always coming out from this js file).

And I can see from fiddler that this parameter is always the same, so I need a way to just extract it from a request that is sent by a headless browser.

I saw [this](https://github.com/kyungw00k/nightmare-webrequest-addon) addon for a nightmare.js, but cannot figure out how to use it.

Maybe that's a stupid question, sorry in advance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need this. I found my solution with Nightmare module and [this](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/1308) link. Replaced onBeforeSendHeaders with onBeforeRequest and used details.uploadData.